# icloud ubiquity token not nil on ios 8 and but on ios 9

Tags: ios, debugging, ios8, ios9, icloud

We have iOS Unity3d game. We use prime31 iCloud plugin
We use Xcode 7.2 for our builds with Latest iOS SDK
We log ubiquity token on app start
On iOS8 token is not nil, and icloud is working
On iOS9 token is nil (same build).
On both devices we are logged in into icloud under the same account.

What can be a reason? Why ubiquity token on ios9 is nil?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCloud is working now. We enabled iCLoud drive in iCloud settings on device. (this etting replaced Docuemnts and Data in iOS 9).